# GoogleCaptcha roadblock in website scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, recaptcha

I am currently working on a scraper for aniworld.to.
My goal is it to enter the anime name and get all of the Episodes downloaded.
I have everything working except one thing...
The websites has a Watch button. That Button redirects you to `https://aniworld.to/redirect/SOMETHING` and that Site has a captcha which means the link is not in the html...
Is there a way to bypass this/get the link in python? Or a way to display the captcha so I can solve it?
Because the captcha only appears every lightyear.
The only thing I need from that page is the redirect link. It looks like this:
`https://vidoza.net/embed-something.html`
My very very wip code is here if it helps: https://github.com/wolfswolke/aniworld_scraper

Comment: From what I read when the captcha is solved it gets stored in a cookie.
Can I export the Cookie from my browser and give it to python?
Maby open a chrome window with the redirect -> Answer the redirect Captcha and then automatically saving the cookie and using it for the next time it opens a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mitchdu showed me how to do it.
If anyone else needs help here is my code: https://github.com/wolfswolke/aniworld_scraper/blob/main/src/logic/captcha.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from threading import Thread

import os
def open_captcha_window(full_url):
    working_dir = os.getcwd()
    path_to_ublock = r'{}\extensions\ublock'.format(working_dir)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("app=" + full_url)
    options.add_argument("window-size=423,705")
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    if os.path.exists(path_to_ublock):
        options.add_argument('load-extension=' + path_to_ublock)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.get(full_url)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100, 0.3)
    wait.until(lambda redirect: redirect.current_url != full_url)

    new_page = driver.current_url
    Thread(target=threaded_driver_close, args=(driver,)).start()
    return new_page


def threaded_driver_close(driver):
    driver.close()
```